# Как узнать свои координаты?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Добрый вечер, проблема такова.
Как узнать свои координаты Google map api v2 android.
И как поставить вместо стандартного маркера обозначающего мое местоположение, другой маркер?

Answer (score 2):

Господи, накидали новичку советов... Юрий, во-первых, в манифесте должны быть прописаны правильные permissions и свой id, который ты получил для debug версии приложения. Без этого у тебя и карты не покажутся в Activity. Дальше: чтобы узнать свои координаты, нужно получить доступ к провайдерам местоположения. Тут уже определяй сам, что тебе нужно. GPS или просто по сети/Wi-Fi. У меня в приложении функция проверяет наличие GPS и устанавливает слушателя. Также устанавливаю слушателя координат и по сети (Интернет):

```
private void checkGPS() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    final boolean gpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!gpsEnabled && gpsAllowed)
        createGPSAlert();

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
    // updates
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 10, mMapDelegate);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1, 10, mMapDelegate);
}
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы добавить маркет на карту, нужно найти координаты (они придут из кода выше) и создать из них объект класса LatLng. У меня координаты - поле класса, поэтому моя функция выглядит вот так:
`protected void setNewPosition() {
  
  if (mCoords == null)
   return;
  
  CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mCoords, 17.0f);
  mMap.animateCamera(update);

  if (mMarker != null)
   mMarker.setPosition(mCoords);
  else
  {
   mMarker = mMap.addMarker(mOpts);
   mMarker.setDraggable(true);
  }
 }`

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы мои координаты хранились в переменной?

LatLng pos = new LatLng();

Comment: А как из этого всего определить название города?

Comment: @Чекист, это уже нужно использовать API распознавания адресов.

Answer (score 1):

Письмо от гугла:

> Мы связываемся с вами, потому что ваш
> адрес электронной почты, связанный с
> ключом Google Maps JavaScript API v2
> используется для следующих доменов:  °
> %domain_name%  Как Вам должно быть
> известно, период устаревания в три
> года для версии 2 JavaScript API Карт
> заканчивается в мае 2013 года. После
> этой даты API больше не будет
> поддерживаться, и функции могут не
> функционировать как ожидается. В
> какой-то момент, ваши карты на V2
> могут перестать работать полностью. 
> Хорошей новостью является то, что
> Google Maps Javascript API v3 является
> более надежной и обладают большим
> функционалом, чем v2, и для
> подавляющего большинства сайтов нет
> проблем с миграцией на V3. Поэтому мы
> настоятельно рекомендуем вам
> просмотреть наши руководства по
> миграции, а также стремиться
> мигрировать до мая 2013 года.

Comment: Так у меня в https://code.google.com/apis/console/ только 
Google Maps Android API v2

Comment: у это avaScript API v2, а в вопросе имеется версия карт для андроид, где последняя версия апи это вторая

Comment: Прошу прощения! А минусовать то зачем?

Comment: Извольте, я не минусовал

Comment: я @Andreichу

Answer (score 0):

Что касается вашего местоположения, то вот так

```
Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
```

что касается второго, то не могу сказать 100% правильное решение, но этот слой можно отключить, на сколько мне известно и подписаться на прослушку местоположения, в котором можно будет поместить маркер в нужном месте.

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location location)
                {

                }
            });
```

ЗЫ: да, решение с маркером не очень красивое, и я знаю, что на старых картах более элегантное решение, но я предложил первый рабочий вариант, который пришел в голову

Comment: Дай бог вам здоровья, мил человек)

Comment: Я совсем новичок, но все же.

Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();

А как передать значение вот в эту переменную;
LatLng mypos = new LatLng();

Comment: LatLng mypos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())