# Изменить местоположение MyLocationButton в GoogleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Как перенести кнопку `Мое местоположение` со стандартного место на `ActionBar` в `GoogleMaps v2`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну во первых Action Bar сейчас является устаревшим! Будьте в тренде и используйте toolbar! Toolbar поддерживается в ОС Android с 2.2

Вот пример хороший для Вас https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-toolbar-example/

Во вторых никак, придется реализоваь свою кнопку с определением местоположения.

Вот Вам один из вариантов реализации кнопки - определение местопложения:

```
private LatLng fromPosition;

FAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraFromPosition();    
        }
    });
    private void cameraFromPosition() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(fromPosition)      
                .zoom(17)                   
                .bearing(180)                
                .tilt(80)                  
                .build(); 
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Что такое FAB и как с ним работать: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/

Comment: Ну теперь я в тренде, перевел все приложение под toolbar :D я пытался реализовать свою кнопку местоположения, но получается не точно, т.к он определяет последнее место положение, ваше метод не работает

Comment: Ну это алгоритм кнопки)) а сам алгоритм большой определения местоположения)

Comment: Ну я так понял реализовать алгоритм место положения можно только через `LastKnownLocation`?

Comment: Да-да + еще `requestLocationUpdates` и `LocationChanged`, все это поможет) Еще нужно проверки делать, если гпс подключен и что делать если не подключен)

Comment: вот тут еще в обсуждениях код, который Вам поможет, правда там он не доведен до ума, но есть с чего начать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/217653/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-